# Use " quote in a German document

Tags: quoting, german

I have a German document with snippets of code where I need the " symbol as it is. Normally, if I insert an empty space after it, I get it printed, but this does not always work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\texttt{inventar <- read\_excel(" inventar.xlsx")}

\end{document}
```

Generates:

[image]

---

For the record:

```
\texttt{inventar <- read\_excel(``inventar.xlsx'')}.
```

Typesets the following (two single quote chars):

[image]

---

Is there a pragmatic way I can print these quotes reliably?

Comment: You could use `"{}` but since that looks like code you should probably consider switching to some dedicated package (like `listings`, `minted`, ...).

Comment: @campa That worked, indeed! I would not want to switch to listings because that is in-text.

Comment: Well, then you could just use verbatim (with `\verb`) instead of `\texttt`. In this way you don't have to escape stuff like the underscore.

Comment: That is also true. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @JohnKormylo You get 2 single quote chars typeset, that would not work for a programming example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngerman` makes `"` active to type Umlauts (and ß). If you don't have a lot of code (in which case I would recommend a dedicated package) use a simple `\verb`. Alternatively, if for some reason (e.g. the string appears in the argument of some other macro) you can add an empty group after `"` or use the macro `\textquotedbl`; for the latter you need the `T1` font encoding but if you are writing in German that should be used anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

Possible:
\texttt{inventar <- read\_excel("{}inventar.xlsx")}

Also possible:
\texttt{inventar <- read\_excel(\textquotedbl inventar.xlsx\textquotedbl)}

Much, much easier:
\verb+inventar <- read_excel("inventar.xlsx")+

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was also getting trouble with \verb{} because of the curly brackets, your example with the + delimiter is good. Learnt 2 things today, thank you!

Comment: @Luis `\verb` doesn't use braces: it uses the first character following it as delimiter. I used here `+` but you can use whatever you want. Of course, if your string involves a `+` you should use something else. The vertical pipe `|` is also often used.

Comment: @Luis generally you cannot use `{}` with `\verb`, it needs the same char at both ends as its processing is very different than normal macros

Comment: @daleif Does that mean that I could use it as `\verb{something{` ?

Comment: @Luis feel free to try

Comment: @daleif I did ;)